# Parsing a variable in bash - line by line and storing the value in a another variable

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, console, output

I am writing a nagios script that will alert me if any of my AWS service limit is about to reach its threshold.

What I have now:

```
aws --profile=profile-name support describe-trusted-advisor-check-result --language en --check-id eW7HH0l7J9 --query "result.sort_by(flaggedResources[],&metadata[2])[].metadata" --output text --region us-east-1 | grep Yellow
```

and the output of the above command is

```
eu-west-1   VPC Internet gateways   5   4   Yellow
eu-west-1   VPC VPCs    5   4   Yellow
```

I would like to parse the output line by line and collect the values: region and service; notify the user about the same.

For instance I would like to notify the user that

```
echo "The $1 has reached its limit in region $2"
where $1 would be internet gateway and $2 would be eu-west-1
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: Is the output of the aws command tab separated?

Comment: @dood yes they are.

Comment: Can't you just pipe the output of your AWS command to AWK with FS="\t" then and print out your message?

Comment: @Kishorepandey : what is your expected output for your 2nd line? Or the above is one continuous big line?

Comment: @Inian which second line are you talking about?

Comment: eu-west-1   VPC VPCs    5   4   Yellow -- a separate line or part of the whole line?

Comment: @Inian They all are part of the line, separated by tabs.

Comment: @Kishorepandey : you can check my solution below and provide feedback of the same.

Comment: @Inian Sorry, but can't find your solution in the answers section below? did you by any chance forgot to post it here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130514/discussion-between-inian-and-kishore-pandey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that grepping for "yellow" is your condition, the following should do the trick. What do you think?

```
aws --profile=profile-name support describe-trusted-advisor-check-result --language en --check-id eW7HH0l7J9 --query "result.sort_by(flaggedResources[],&metadata[2])[].metadata" --output text --region us-east-1 | grep Yellow |\
awk -F"\t" '{print "The", $3, "has reached its limit in region", $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` `process substitution <()`. Put the below lines in `sample.sh`, set execute permissions `chmod +x sample.sh` and run the script as `bash script.sh`

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while read -r first _ second third _ 
 do
      printf "%s %s %s\n" "The $second $third has reached its limit in region $first"
 done< <(aws --profile=profile-name support describe-trusted-advisor-check-result --language en --check-id eW7HH0l7J9 --query "result.sort_by(flaggedResources[],&metadata[2])[].metadata" --output text --region us-east-1 | grep Yellow)
```

Running the script now,

```
$ bash script.sh
The Internet gateways has reached its limit in region eu-west-1  
The VPCs 5 has reached its limit in region eu-west-1
```

Comment: @rici : Agreed op's output was one big line tab separated

Comment: @Inian Thanks for the reply, but as mentioned by rici, it only reads one line and I looking for a solution that could iterate over N lines. The example in the question has two lines, but that could change. Nevertheless I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Kishorepandey :Refer my update, for a line by line processing logic

Comment: @Kishorepandey: refer my latest update, fixed the issue.

Comment: @Inian Thanks a ton.